# Finding all sizes of cuboids with given volume

Tags: algorithm

I have an interval of integers and I need to find all unique cuboids which have a volume that falls within said interval.

I came up with a loop that goes over all uniqe combinations of 3 numbers (size of the cuboid) (1x1x1, 1x1x2, ...; also 2x1x1 is considered the same as 1x1x2) from 1 to the upper range of the interval, and then checks if the calculated volume falls within the interval. This solution works perfectly if the upper range isn't is too large. But if the interval ends in thousands the solution becomes very slow.

I am not really interested in code as I am in an algorithm on how to solve this differently. How would you go about solving this?

Comment: what's a cuboid in this context?

Comment: an object of which you can calculate the volume V = a*b*c https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid

Comment: …**in this context**? Meaning: what is the restriction on the numbers you use to construct this?

Comment: Sorry, the cuboids sides are whole numbers, examples 3x2x2, 2x2x2, 1x1x3

Comment: the sides are whole numbers, no other restricitons, if given the volume of 15 an cuboid with sides 15x1x1 is valid

Comment: How is the "solution becoming slow" if you are not using code?

Comment: I have already written the code so I can see. Its just that i am interested in a more "general" algorithm rahter than pasting code. Also I am using C, which would propably limit the amount of responses I would get if "I requested code."

Comment: Please use a spelling checker. Correct the title, too.

Comment: Can you please specify the input here? Are you just given two integers x and y and you have to generate all cuboids whose sides are between x and y and volume is between v1 and v2? Or there is no restriction side length and only volume range is provided? (Please tag me by my handle - @displayName - when you reply)

Answer (score 1):

If your code is slow it's probably trying ranges of values that could be discarded immediately, or it's overly complicated and calculates square or cubic roots in loop conditions and such. Try something simple like the code example below, where I make sure a ≤ b ≤ c to avoid duplicates:

```js
if (Math.cbrt == undefined) // cubic root fix for older browsers
    Math.cbrt = function(x) {var n = 1; while (n * n * n <= x) ++n; return n - 1;}

function cuboids(min_volume, max_volume) {
    var results = [];
    var cr = Math.cbrt(max_volume);
    for (var a = 1; a <= cr; a++) {
        var sr = Math.sqrt(max_volume / a);
        for (var b = a; b <= sr; b++) {
            var lower = Math.ceil(min_volume / (a * b));
            var upper = Math.floor(max_volume / (a * b));
            for (var c = Math.max(b, lower); c <= upper; c++) {
                results.push([a, b, c]);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}

var results = cuboids(99900, 100000);
for (var i in results) document.write(results[i].join("*") + "<br>");
```

Comment: @Sopel There's a range between min_volume and max_volume, so there could be more than one c for any a and b.

Answer (score 0):

Define your target interval I = [A … B], giving you M=B-A+1 different integer volumes.

You'll have to consider each of these in isolation.

For any of these target volumes v, a naive algorithm (that's probably still better than yours) would be:

1. find the prime number factorization of that; let that yield Ω(n) factors; store them as a list A.
2. {v,1,1} is possible tuple.
3. for i in 1…Ω(n):
   3.1. r = prod(A_l for l = 1 to i)
   3.2  {r, v/r, 1} is possible tuple
   3.3 for k in i+1…Ω(n):
   3.3.1 s = prod(A_m for m = i+1 to k)
   3.3.2 {r, s, v/r/s} is possible tuple

This algorithm is naive because it assumes that finding A is easy. In fact, you'd ideally already note down all the tuples while creating A.

Comment: Thank you. But I cant really use this solution. I am afraid that this solution would be really painful to implement in C. I am unfortunately quite limited in what I can use. Including memory and computational time.

Comment: Huh? No, this would be extremely straight forward to implement in C (implementation: you explicitly said you didn't care about in your question)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably loop over pairs for the first two dimensions, then directly calculate the min and max values of the third dimension to get in the interval, and save earlier solutions based on the product of the first two dimensions. Something like:

```
volume_interval = (Vmin, Vmax)
solution_intervals = {}
for w = 1 to n do
    for d = w to n do
        // see whether we've already encountered this case before
        if solution_intervals[w*d] is not defined then
            // compute min and max height to get in volume interval
            min = ceiling(volume_interval.Vmin / (w*d))
            max = floor(volume_interval.Vmax / (w*d))
            solution_intervals[w*d] = (min, max)
        // look up precomputed solution
        soln = solution_intervals[w*d]
        // print out every possible set of dimensions
        for i = soln.min to soln.max do
            print w, d, h
```